# Type error after importing custom class in Django

Tags: python, django, typeerror

I have `test.py` file with a `python class` added. class code looks like this.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname):
        self.fname = firstname
        self.lname = lastname
        self.email = firstname + "." + lastname + "@test.com"

    def Get_Fullname(self):
        return self.fname+ " " + self.lname
```

`test.py` file is directly under the app folder. my `view.py` file look like this

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from test import *

@csrf_exempt
def New_Function():
    myFunc = foo('Test','User')
    return HttpResponse(myFunc.Get_Fullname())
```

added the below into `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$','app.views.home',name='home'),
    url(r'^functionCall/','app.views.New_Function'),
]
```

in `java-script` i have

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '/functionCall/',
        method:'POST',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
        }
    });
});
```

when i load my page i'm getting `TypeError at /functionCall/` and `New_Function() takes no arguments (1 given)`

What am i doing wrong over here, new thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django view function takes an `HttpRequest` object as its first parameter so you should add `request` argument:

```
@csrf_exempt
def New_Function(request):
    myFunc = foo('Test','User')
    return HttpResponse(myFunc.Get_Fullname())
```